# Como acessar o valor em outro component?

Tags: react

Gente comecei a usar React recentemente, e estou com um problema.
Preciso que quando o usuário clicar no botão do MyComponent o incremento é mostrado no App.

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        itemCount: 0
      };

    }
     addItem() {
      this.setState({
        itemCount: this.state.itemCount + 1
      });
    }

    render() {
      return  (
        <div>

          <button onClick={this.addItem.bind(this)}>Click Me</button>
          <h1 >Current Item Count: {this.state.itemCount}</h1>

        </div>
      );
    }
  };
```

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.child = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      itemCount: 0
    }

  }
  onClick = () => {
    this.child.current.addItem();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyComponent ref={this.child} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Da maneira que está sendo feita, o valor não é passado para o component App.

Comment: você tem que aprender alguma ferramenta de gerenciamento de estado, tipo: Redux, Mobx, Flux, etc. Ou você pode aprender sobre [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Ah ótimo, obrigado. Vou aprender sobre Redux. Pra essa finalidade, acabei utilizando o localstorage. Você recomenda ?

Comment: Não sei para que tipo de finalidade você usaria o localStorage na vida real, mas como você disse _"o valor não é passado para o component App"_ então eu recomendo mesmo é que use um gerenciador de estado

Comment: Beleza. Obrigado.